# Are two separate limit cycles in a dynamical system possible

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics, limit-cycles

In all the examples I've seen before with two limit cycles, the limit cycles are always concentric (there is an unstable point at center, a stable limit cycle on the middle and an unstable limit cycle at the outside). Is it possible to imagine a dynamic system with two limit cycles are separate (one is not inside the other)?

Comment: You define one vector field that yields an unstable equilibrium at $x=-2$ with an attractive limit cycle around it with $r=1$, and another vector field with an unstable equilibrium at $x=+2$ with an attractive limit cycle around it with $r=1$. And then you switch between them based on the sign of $x$. Should work.